# Enable submit button on check of checkbox and send data to controller.js

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a checkbox. On tick of that checkbox, I am displaying a textbox and a drop-down menu. I want to add a submit button which should also be displayed on tick of the checkbox only. This is not working for me. Also, I have to send data (value of textbox and selected value from dropdown) to my controller.js using that submit button.
**Edited** : What i need to do is i have to select data from dropdown and enter text data and I need to send both data to spring controller through angularjs controller.

```
Here is my code : .html

    <div class="form-group">
            <div ng-controller="release">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-centered col-fixed">
                        <label for="cloneRelease" translate="release.form.cloneRelease">CloneRelease</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cloneRelease" ng-model="ticketed">
                            <div ng-show="ticketed">
                                Release Name:<input type="text" ng-show="ticketed" id="newReleaseName">
                                Release To Clone<select ng-show="ticketed" ng-repeat="release in releaseName">
                                <option  value={{release}}>{{release}}</option>
                                </select>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" translate="" data-dismiss="modal" 
                                ng-click="cloneRelease(release,newReleaseName)">CloneRelease</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

controller.js

$scope.cloneRelease = function($release,$newReleaseName){
            var dataObj = {
            oldReleaseName : $scope.release,
            newReleaseName : $scope.newReleaseName,
        };
        console.log('inside clone release'+dataObj);
        $http.post('cloneReleaseController/cloneRelease',dataObj).success(function (data) { 

        }); 
        }

Spring controller

public void cloneRelease(String oldReleaseName ,String newReleaseName, @RequestBody ReleaseDAO releaseDAO){
        System.out.println("inside clone controller"+oldReleaseName+" "+newReleaseName);
}
```

Comment: maybe use ng-show="ticketed==true"   // only show button if checkbox is true. Don't you do this on the other checkbox?

Comment: No its not working. ng-show="ticketed==true" Its not working

Answer (score 1):

Please do this one

```
<div ng-controller="release">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-centered col-fixed">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cloneRelease" ng-model="ticketed">
    <div ng-show="ticketed">
      <input type="text" ng-show="ticketed" id="newReleaseName" ng-model="releaseName">
      <select ng-show="ticketed" ng-repeat="release in releaseName">
        <option  value={{release}}>{{release}}</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" translate="" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cloneRelease()">CloneRelease</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<div ng-show="ticketed">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" translate="" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cloneRelease()">CloneRelease</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't put submit button in same div tag as there are other fields too. Is there any way to put submit button in other div tag and bind it with checkbox?

Comment: I am passing data from angularjs controller to spring controller but its not reaching to the controller.

Comment: on submit button you can call function in controller

Comment: Its comming to angularjs controller but its not reaching spring controller.

Comment: i cannot figure out what is issue? hide button or passing data to spring controller?

Comment: Now i resolved the hide button issue but couldn't pass data to spring controller. Is there any other way where i can show you my code??

Comment: spring controller hosted in locally?